# Nested HashMap Creation in Android

Tags: java, android, hashmap

In my application I have 3 tabs that contain ListViews depending on what the selection was in the previous tabs. Basically, the 1st tab will list restaurants, 2nd tab will lists submenus of the selected restaurant, the 3rd menu will lists the items of that selected submenu, and then when an item is selected, it will display some nutritional info about that item. I don't know the best way to organize the restaurants/submenus/item, but the way I was thinking was a nested HashMap like the following.

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double[]>>>
```

What I don't know how to do, is efficiently build this map where it is easy to add/remove things in the future. I was looking at xml, but I could not figure out how to do it. If I did it this way, I would also need help writing the Java code to parse through the xml and put it all into the correct place in its map. I am not sure if you need to use tags or if you can just have an xml file that utilizes map and then just kind of 'import' it into your java project. I don't think that hard coding every single item in Java would be very efficient, so I was hoping I could get some help.

Possble, like this? Not exactly filled out, but I really didn't know what I was doing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<util:map name="foodmapping">
 <restaurant key="McDonalds">
  <util:map>

  </util:map>"

 </restaurant>
 <restaurant key="Starbucks">
  <value>2
  </value>
 </restaurant>
</util:map>
```

Comment: "I don't know the best way to organize the restaurants/submenus/item, but the way I was thinking was a nested HashMap like the following." -- why not use a database?

Comment: @CommonsWare: I am still new to Android, so I thought using something familiar like a HashMap (close to Dictionary in Python) would be easier. Do you have any good tutorials on using a SQLite database?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be andriod specific. I don't know android But the basic principle that i use for nested hashmaps. The initialization should be the furthest nested first

I may not have the best answer. I am no good at explaining. But here is a code example. 
NOTE: This may not work on android as i said i never worked with android. This is basic java code.

```java
HashMap<String,HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Object>>>example1 = new HashMap<>();
// Init should be furthest first.
HashMap<String,Object>furthest = new HashMap<>();
// This will start up middle level.
HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Object>>middle = new HashMap<>();
// Now that that is done. We can load up values
middle.put("first",furthest);
//Now middle is loaded with basic startup.
example1.put("first",middle);
//Now this initialization example is complete. 
example1.get("first").get("first").put("lowestSecond",/*SOME OBJECT HERE*/); // This is an example of how to put more data into the furthest level down.
```

I do not believe this is the best answer for you. But that is the basic code i would use to initiate a multi level hashmap